# Remove the thin white line between pages in PDFView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

How to remove the thin white line between pages in PDFView

I tried to set the `pageShadowsEnabled` to false and `displaysPageBreaks` to false
I event tried to set the pageBreakMargins to 0
[image: White line in PDFView]

this is the the code

```
        pdfView = PDFView(frame: pdfViewContainer.bounds)
                
        pdfView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        pdfView?.autoScales = true        
        pdfView?.pageShadowsEnabled = false
        pdfView?.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        pdfView?.displaysPageBreaks = false
                        
        pdfViewContainer.addSubview(pdfView!)
```